# Eloquent hasManyThrough Alias

Tags: php, sql, orm, eloquent

I have two tables like so

```
users
id|username|...
1 |foo
2 |bar

relationship
id|user_one|user_two
1 |1       |2
2 |2       |1
```

Then in my User model I have the following function

```
public function friends($user_id)
{
    return $this->find($user_id)->hasManyThrough('User', 'Relationship', 'user_one', 'id');
}
```

The error I get is

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'users'
```

So the question is, is there a way to alias one of the tables in the query that is created by Eloquent?